# Swift 3 - Http post to Https wcf web service

Tags: xcode, wcf, https, swift3, urlsession

In my xcode console application (10.12), i m using http post requests for sending data to wcf web service. If that web service works with http there is no any problem. But if i change to secure (https) connection then i can not communicate with web service. I m getting 404 error code.

```
class request :NSObject,URLSessionDelegate{


func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didBecomeInvalidWithError error: Error?) {
    if let err = error {
        print("Error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        print("Error. Giving up")
    }
}


func makeHTTPPostRequest(path: String, params: Dictionary<String,AnyObject>) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: path)! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"


    do  {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10

        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration,delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)


        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

            print(response)

        })
        task.resume()

    }
    catch{

    }

}
```

And web service code someting like that :

```
     [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Test", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    [OperationContract]
    string Test(string name);
```

I m calling method :

```
var params = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()
```

params["name"] = "Hi" as AnyObject?

var r = request()
r.makeHTTPPostRequest(path:"https://192.168.1.104/sample/Service1.svc/Test",params:params)

This is response from server :

```
{ status code: 404, headers {
"Cache-Control" = private;
"Content-Length" = 0;
Date = "Sat, 25 Mar 2017 14:59:29 GMT";
Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
"Set-Cookie" = "ASP.NET_SessionId=l2omo5wflafesmcw2j23sw4t; path=/; HttpOnly";
"X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
"X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";}
```

So what i m doing wrong ? Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake, wrong web.config configuration. 
The code above works fine.

Best